# simple dictionary manipulation in python

Tags: python

```
groups = ['A','B','C']

ranges = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

my_dict = {}
for g in groups:
   my_dict[g] = ???
```

The result (my_dict) should be as follows:

```
{'A': array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64), 'B': array([4,5,6], dtype=int64)), 'C': array([7,8,9], dtype=int64)}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

First I would turn your `ranges` in to properly sized chunks:

```
>>> ranges = zip(*[iter(ranges)]*len(groups))
>>> print(ranges)
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

This will create chunks of `len(groups)` items which you can then feed to `zip()` in the second part.

Then create the dictionary, using a dictionary comprehension and `zip()`.

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> my_dict = {g: array(r) for g, r in zip(groups, ranges)}
>>> print(my_dict)
{'A': array([1, 2, 3]), 'C': array([7, 8, 9]), 'B': array([4, 5, 6])}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> groups = ['A','B','C']
>>> ranges = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> dict(zip(groups,
...          (list(itertools.islice(it, 3)) for it in [iter(ranges)]*3)))
{'A': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [7, 8, 9], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}
```